# jsonwebtoken: expiresIn does not expires?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am trying to set the token to be expired in one hour following the example from the [guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim):

```
jwt.sign({
  data: 'foobar'
}, 'secret', { expiresIn: 60 * 60 })
```

But the toke never expires in a few hours later:

```
curl -XGET -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNTU4OTAzMDI3LCJleHAiOjE1NTg5MDY2Mjd9.8uHKDM4Hgy08kw_0CLib2QnzqudeC_RsIlh8e9uURT0' 'http://localhost:3000/api/users'
```

Have I missing something?

How do I set it to expire in 1 or 5 minutes?

The code for verifying the token:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import config from '../config'

export default async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next()

    if(ctx.req.hasOwnProperty('headers') && ctx.req.headers.hasOwnProperty('authorization')) {
      ctx.req.user = jwt.verify(ctx.req.headers['authorization'], config.JWT_SECRET, function (err, payload) {
        console.log(payload)
      })
    } else {
      // If there is no autorization header, return 401 status code.
      ctx.throw(401, 'Protected resource, use Authorization header to get access')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.status = err.status || 500

    ctx.type = 'json'
    ctx.body = {
      status: ctx.status,
      message: err.message
    }

    ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx)
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks ok. What code are you using to verify the token?

Comment: @Matt I have updated my question with the code that I use for verifying the token. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`jwt.verify`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) function in the question code sample is using a callback function to return it's asynchronous result.

Koa is promise based and won't pick up this callback result or catch any errors being raised (including a `TokenExpiredError`). The verify `err` is completely ignored at the moment.

`jwt.verify` can be converted into a promise, or if you don't supply the callback argument the function will return synchronously. The `try`/`catch` will then work as expected.

```
import util from 'util'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import config from '../config'

export const verifyPromise = util.promisify(jwt.verify)

export default async function verifyToken(ctx, next){

  if(!ctx.req.hasOwnProperty('headers') || !ctx.req.headers.hasOwnProperty('authorization')) {
    return ctx.throw(401, 'Protected resource, use Authorization header to get access')
  }

  try {
    let payload = await verifyPromise(ctx.req.headers['authorization'], config.JWT_SECRET, {})
    console.log(payload)
  }
  catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError'){
      return ctx.throw(401, 'Protected resource, token expired')
    }

    console.error(err)
    return ctx.throw(500, 'Protected resource, token error')

  }

  await next()

}
```

The [`jwt.sign`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) function takes a number as seconds or a string description of time from [zeit/ms](https://github.com/zeit/ms)

```
{ expiresIn: 1 * 60 }
{ expiresIn: '1m' }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tested the token with `koa-jwt` and the expiration works ok but `jsonwebtoken` is definitely more flexible. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim) it says that

> This means that the exp field should contain the **number of seconds** since the epoch.

So:

- 1 minute => `60`
- 5 minutes => `60 * 5`

Which gives

```
// Expires in 5 minutes
jwt.sign({
  data: 'foobar'
}, 'secret', { expiresIn: 5 * 60 })
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code assumes that the expiration and issued at properties are defined as milliseconds (60000 milliseconds = 60 seconds = 1 minute).

```
  var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret,{ expiresIn: 60});
```